# How to get value from JSON File and display on Website

Tags: json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a Node.JS Website. I would like to retrieve data from a json file to correctly display on the website. How do I go about doing so. I am new to Node.JS and do not understand where I write the scripts.

```
   {
    "id": "dfd9722a-3ca3-48e7-af2b-633e33d626b5",
    "clientId": "4ef8da99-07ee-4f40-8ea5-be13f4592a62",
    "source": "D346618B-2C9F-4765-940A-B9369BD67114",
    "destination": "",
    "priority": "MEDIUM",
    "reliability": "BEST_EFFORT",
    "eventTime": 1535036080788,
    "eventTimeAsString": "2018-08-23T14:54:40Z",
    "sender": "",
    "type": "DATA",
    "properties": {},
    "direction": "FROM_DEVICE",
    "receivedTime": 1535036083635,
    "receivedTimeAsString": "2018-08-23T14:54:43Z",
    "payload": {
        "format": "urn:oracle:hospitality:lock:attributes",
        "data": {
            "locked": false,
                "Source_FirstName":"John",
                "Source_LastName":"Dunbar"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the **John** (source_firstname) **Dunbar** (source_lastname) to appear on my site. I am using Node.JS, express, and handlebars (as my template engine).

```
<div id="body-container">
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo-content">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="welcome">
        <p>Welcome {{!-- <-- Here goes JSON values }} to Node Park</p>
    </div>
</div> 
{{!-- end of header --}}
```

Here is my Node.JS code

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');

// Init App
const app = express();

// Load View Engine
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', 
layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

// Home Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Node.JS',
    hotel: 'NODEMON'
  });
});

// Start Server
app.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('Port 5000 open for business.');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can require the `json` file in your service.

```
//If the json file is in the same root
const json = require("./data.json");

app.get('/', function(req, res){      
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Node.JS',
    hotel: 'NODEMON',
    firtsName : json.payload.data.Source_FirstName,
    lastName : json.payload.data.Source_LastName
  });
});
```

And access the `firtsName` and `lastName` in the html

```
<div id="body-container">
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo-content">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="welcome">
        <p>Welcome {{ firtsName }} {{ lastName }} to Node Park</p>
    </div>
</div> 
{{!-- end of header --}}
```

Comment: For Some reason it is returning "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined", any idea why?

Comment: Check the output @FreshOceans

Comment: I found the issue, my json data was in an array. I removed the the [] and it works now. Or I could have just added json[0].payload.data.Source_LastName. THANKS!!

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Got it @Nic3500

Answer (score -1):

```
const json = require('./your.json');

// Home Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Redwood Welcome',
    hotel: 'Redwood Hotel',
    source_firstname: json.source_firstname,
    source_lastname: json.source_lastname,
  });
});

<div id="welcome">
        <p>Welcome {{source_firstname}} {{source_lastname}} to Node Park</p>
    </div>
```